# R to calculate the unique count for Overlap Categories

Tags: r, categories, overlapping

I have been so frustrated to count the number of clients who made conversion or not in the 3 single categories (app, desktop, web) scenarios and the rest of the overlapping categories (app & Web, app & desktop, web & desktop, app & web & desktop) scenarios. Here is the sample dataset I am working on.

I could figure out the single category count with the aggregate and group_by function in r, however, I can't really figure out how to work on the overlap categories.

Really really thanks so much if someone could help me on this!!! Thanks!!!

```
df <- data.frame(list(ClientID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3" , "3" , "3" , "4" ),
                     device = c("App", "Web", "App", "Web", "Web", "App", "Desktop", "App", "App", "Web"),
                     conversion = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1")) )
```

Below is the desired outcome:

```
Scenario                With Conversion      Without Conversion 
App                          
Web                          
Desktop
App & Web
App & Desktop
Web & Desktop
App & Desktop & Web
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare a list of device combinations (i.e. all 7 possibilities), and then use `setequal()` and `unique()` in a helper function, like this

1. list of device combinations, using `combn()`

```
device_combinations = unlist(
  sapply(1:3, \(i) combn(c("App", "Web" ,"Desktop"), i, simplify = F)),
  recursive = F
)
```

2. Helper function, `f` (takes a list of devices, and indicates whether  the unique list of devices meets each of the device combinations (it can meet at max one only, by using `unique()` and `setequal()`

```
f <- function(d) sapply(device_combinations, \(ds) setequal(ds, unique(d)))
```

3. Now apply the function by `conversion` and `ClientID`, unnest, count by `conversion` and `Scenario` and pivot to your desired wide format

```
df %>% 
  group_by(conversion,ClientID) %>%
  summarize(v = f(device), .groups="drop") %>%
  unnest(v) %>% 
  mutate(
    Scenario=rep(sapply(device_combinations,paste,collapse=","),length.out=n()),
    conversion =if_else(conversion=="0", "Without Conversion", "With Conversion")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Scenario, conversion) %>% 
  summarize(ct = sum(v), .groups="drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Scenario, names_from = conversion,values_from = ct)
```

Output:

```
  Scenario        `With Conversion` `Without Conversion`
  <chr>                       <int>                <int>
1 App                             1                    0
2 App,Desktop                     0                    1
3 App,Web                         0                    1
4 App,Web,Desktop                 0                    0
5 Desktop                         0                    0
6 Web                             2                    1
7 Web,Desktop                     0                    0
```

Comment: Your counts aren't quite right—but I really like the approach you used! It's probably something really mundane throwing it off.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Brilliant!!!!! 
Your code works on my master data too! 
but the code is quite difficult that I don't think I can write it out myself  T_T 
I originally thought it could be a Venn diagram or something

Comment: but ya I agree with Kat that one calculation seems not correct. Only clients 2 and 4 are purely Web users, the null conversion count for Web only should be 1 that is coming from client 2, if I am correct? 
I think the miscalculation is from Client 1 who 1 also had no conversion on Web but client 1 is App and Web user, not purely Web user.

Comment: ah., okay, I didn't realize you wanted uniqueness. I'll need to revise. My apologies.. It would help perhaps to put your expected numbers in your expected output, instead of leaving blank

Comment: See edit, where I have revised the helper function `f`

Comment: yaaaa it works!!! really thanks and it's correct now!!! It's really difficult for me to code the first 2 steps. Sorry I should have put my expected output clear! Will do so next time! 
It helps a lot and thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add my answer in addition to the one that's already here.

#### Updated based on your comment

This doesn't look all that neat, but it does do what you're expecting. Although the other answer looks far better.

I started by collecting the count of unique customers by conversion by device.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfn <- map(c("0", "1"),
           function(k) {
             with(df[df$conversion == k,], table(device, ClientID)) %>% 
               as.data.frame() %>% filter(Freq > 0) %>% select(-Freq) %>% 
               distinct() %>% group_by(device) %>% summarise(cnt = n())
             }
           )

dfa <- data.frame(device = unique(df$device)) %>% 
  left_join(., dfn[[1]]) %>% setNames(., c("device", "0")) %>% 
  left_join(., dfn[[2]])
names(dfa)[3] <- "1"
dfa[is.na(dfa)] <- 0
dfa
#    device 0 1
# 1     App 2 1
# 2     Web 2 2
# 3 Desktop 1 0
```

Then I wanted the combinations. There are only three here, so I could probably write the combinations faster than coding them. However, I've provided a more dynamic approach.

```
dbls = RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(dfa$device, 2)
#      [,1]    [,2]   
# [1,] App     Desktop
# [2,] App     Web    
# [3,] Desktop Web    
# Levels: App Desktop Web
```

Now I'll use data frame `df` to calculate the counts for the combinations determined in `dbls`.

```
dfb <- map2_dfr(rep(1:nrow(dbls), 2), rep(c("0", "1"), 3), 
    function(x, y){
      gimme = with(df[df$conversion == y, ], table(device, ClientID)) %>% 
        as.data.frame() %>% 
        filter(Freq > 0, device %in% c(dbls[x, 1], dbls[x, 2])) %>% 
        select(-Freq) %>% distinct() %>% group_by(ClientID) %>% 
        mutate(cnt = n()) %>% filter(cnt == 2)
      if(nrow(gimme) == 0){
        c(device = paste0(dbls[x, 1], " & ", dbls[x, 2]),
          wh = y, cnt = 0)
      } else {
        c(device = paste0(dbls[x, 1], " & ", dbls[x, 2]),
          wh = y, cnt = length(unique(gimme$ClientID)))
      }
    }) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "wh", values_from = "cnt")
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   device        `0`   `1`  
#   <chr>         <chr> <chr>
# 1 App & Desktop 1     0    
# 2 App & Web     1     0    
# 3 Desktop & Web 0     0
```

Last, but not least, I combined the two frames.

I don't know which conversion (0 or 1) is with or without, so I just left the markers.

```
rbind(dfa, dfb)
#          device 0 1
# 1           App 2 1
# 2           Web 2 2
# 3       Desktop 1 0
# 4 App & Desktop 1 0
# 5     App & Web 1 0
# 6 Desktop & Web 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much too!! but I think the calculation needs to be grouped by Client ID too, not purely the count of the device. (my bad if I didn't put my question clearly T_T)

Comment: I've undated my answer. It should address what you originally were looking for now. I think your other answer is a bit easier to follow, though!

Comment: thanks so much for sharing another approach!! Both are honestly quite hard for me to code it entirely from scratch me. Brilliant work!!